# matlab callbacks doesn't work on second press

Tags: matlab

I created a gui in matlab ,it consist of three buttons ,edittexts and plot.
On pressing the first button(start) matlab starts execution of 'start callback' which contains a while loop .On pressing the second button(stop button) callback of stop gets executed.Now if i press start button again will it start executing from the first line of callback or somewhere inside the while loop where it left initially when stop button was pressed.
Basically the  problem in my code is that start and stop button works properly on first press but on second time the buttons doesn't work at all.
below is my code:

```
   function matgui1_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

  handles.output = hObject;
  guidata(hObject, handles);

  set(handles.stop,'Enable','off'); 

  s = serial('COM1');
  set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
  set(s,'Timeout',20);
  set(s,'ReadAsyncMode','continuous');
  fopen(s);
  handles=guidata(hObject);
  handles.set=s;
  guidata(hObject,handles);
  function varargout = matgui1_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
  varargout{1} = handles.output;
```

% --- Executes on button press in start.

```
  function start_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

  set(handles.start,'Enable','off');  
  set(handles.Refresh,'Enable','off');
  set(handles.stop,'Enable','on');
  drawnow;
  s=handles.set;
  fprintf(s,'%c','s');
  i=1;
  string1='start';
  set(handles.edit5, 'String', string1);
  drawnow;
  while(1)
  if(s.BytesAvailable>0)
  a = fread(s,1,'uint8');
  t(i)=a;
  drawnow;
  plotData=plot(t,'linewidth',1);
  drawnow;

  grid on;
  drawnow;
  i=i+1; 

   end
   end
   fclose(s)
   delete(s)
```

stop button callback

```
  function stop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

  set(handles.stop,'Enable','off');
  set(handles.start,'Enable','on');  
  set(handles.Refresh,'Enable','on');
  drawnow;
  setup=handles.set;
  fprintf(setup,'%c','g');
  flushinput(setup);
   string1='stop';
   set(handles.edit5, 'String', string1);
```

Comment: "_Now if i press start button again will it start executing from the first line of callback_" ... yes definitely. The callback by itself has no way of knowing if it's its first or Nth run, or knowing where it left off ... unless **you** program something specific to keep count of these things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a high enough reputation to comment, but do you update your handles structure before exiting the start and stop callbacks? So do you have the line
`guidata(hObject, handles);` at the end of them? 
If by the buttons don't work the second time you mean that they are disabled this is likely the cause and the changes you make with set(...) are not preserved outside the specific callback functions.